# Parse json-object to few block

Tags: json, regex

I need parse json-object to few json-subobject using regex. The input is received json-object, for example:

```
[{
"customerId": 906366,
"subscriberId": 1231244,
"realTimeStatusId": 100,
"realTimeStatusDate": "2017-08-04T09:27:39"
}, {
"customerId": 906235,
"subscriberId": 1231244,
"realTimeStatusId": 101,
"realTimeStatusDate": "2017-08-04T09:27:39"
}, {
"customerId": 906235,
"subscriberId": 1231243,
"realTimeStatusId": 100,
"realTimeStatusDate": "2017-08-04T08:27:39"
}]
```

on out i need get few substings. 
First:

```
{
"customerId": 906366,
"subscriberId": 1231244,
"realTimeStatusId": 100,
"realTimeStatusDate": "2017-08-04T09:27:39"
 }
```

Second:

```
{
"customerId": 906235,
"subscriberId": 1231244,
"realTimeStatusId": 101,
"realTimeStatusDate": "2017-08-04T09:27:39"
}
```

and etc.
How I can do it using regex?

Comment: your question is not clear. please explain in detail.

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\{[^}]+\}
```

tested on **regex101**

https://regex101.com/r/PnnqHv/1